# Compilation error of Android Application

Tags: android, android-emulator, compiler-errors

I crated an Application it has
LoginActivity ( Used Login Form with constant credentials)
TestmapActivity  (used Google Map Api - to display Map)

layouts:
Login (LoginActivity)

### myMap  (TestmapActivity)

```
Intent dashboard = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, TestmapActivity.class);

                        // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                        dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(dashboard);
```

---

i compiled the above project with google Api 2.3

successfully installed but when the login was success its raising an error : The App Stopped Unexpectedly

```
11-28 16:44:14.162: E/AndroidRuntime(611): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

11-28 16:44:14.162: E/AndroidRuntime(611): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.androidhive.TestmapActivity
11-28 16:44:14.162: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at com.example.androidhive.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:79)
11-28 16:44:14.162: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
11-28 16:44:14.162: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
11-28 16:44:14.162: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-28 16:44:14.162: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-28 16:44:14.162: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-28 16:44:14.162: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-28 16:44:14.162: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-28 16:44:14.162: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-28 16:44:14.162: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-28 16:44:14.162: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-28 16:44:14.162: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Is `TestmapActivity` defined in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Comment: Make sure you spelled everything correctly in your Android Manifest.

Comment: @wasnville Thank You Very Much friend - i missed it - working fine now